# Android design for very similar (but different) devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

The answer to this may be, 'you poorly designed your app', which is likely as I'm still pretty new to this.

Issue:  I have small game that I created where the background image of the screen is the game board.  On it, are locations for scoreboards (part of the image).  I am using textviews as the different scores that will display on 4 score boards.  My issue that I am trying to address is keeping the textviews placed where I need them, directly over the score board images, when different size and density devices are used.  (things move around).

I have this working great on many different devices and densities using multiple resource qualifiers on my values folders.  For examples...

sw320dp-xhdpi
sw400dp-mdpi

etc.

I am running in to situations where I have two devices that are both xhdpi and their resolutions are very close.

device 1: 1280 x 720
device 2: 1280 x 768

As I have things currently, this will result in both of them using the same dimens file that is being used to place the text views.  Ultimately, this results in one of them aligning things perfectly and the other being slightly off.

Is there a way handle one of them uniquely via a 3rd resource qualifier?

Is there a different way to handle this outside of resource qualifiers?

Did I approach this poorly and there is a much cleaner way to handle what I am trying to do?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: yes  you can place your views in code according to device width height 

lets say you have a 1000 pix height image  and u  need to place a text view on 300 dp from top 

300/1000 * get devise height  will position it in the same place :)

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the in-depth answer you're looking for, but Google announced their [new version of Android Studio](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest) a while back. It includes the ability to make one layout fit all devices. Check it out:

[image: Android Studio 2.2 Interface Blueprint]

Comment: @bboursaw73 Just to be clear, there are XML traits that can be used to do this- the 2.2 preview just makes it way easier. Look at [relational formatting](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to solve this manually.